# Assigning distinct values to leaves in a tree

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, tree, nodes

I am trying to assign numbers to each leaf in a tree.

For example if we have a tree that has 6 leaves, I want the leaves to have the numbers from 0 to 5.

I don't know why my code doesn't work well, I have been trying many times even in recursive ways but it seems I am missing something..

```
   public class Node {

    int index;
    int id;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    // Constructor and setters/getters.

    public static void num(Node n) {

    int ini=0;
    if(n==null)
    {

    }
    if(n.isLeaf())
    {
        n.index=ini;
        ini++;
    }
    if(!n.isLeaf())
    {
        num(n.getleft());
        num(n.getRight());
    }
}
```

Also I wanted to get the number of the leaves in the tree.

For example, Our tree looks like

```
                                  1
                                /   \
                               2     3
                             /  \   / \ 
                            6    9  8  10
                           /
                          4
    public static int numberChild(Node n, int count)

{
    if (n == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n.getleft() == null && n.getRight() == null) {
        return 1 + count;
    } else {
        int lc = numberChild(n.getleft(), count);
        int rc = numberChild(n.getRight(), lc);
        return rc;
    }

}
```

will give me a wrong number of leaves, 2 instead of 4 !

Any Help ?

Comment: Is your tree sorted in any way, and do you want the labels assigned in any order?

Comment: The tree is not sorted, but the leaves are, we start indexing from the left to right. Which means we will need a reverse polish notation.

Comment: I don’t readily see any bugs in your code. Can you try a debugger?

Comment: I didn’t get the part about “assuming that the tree in not a binary tree”. Your `Node` has two decendants, `left` and `right`, that sounds like a binary tree to me.

Comment: @OleV.V. There are bugs. For the Tree drawn above, the number of leaves should be 4, I get only 3. But if the node 6 had 2 leaves, the output would be correct, but when we have a node that has only 1 leaf, I get a wrong output.

And I edited my post, all I wanted to say is that the tree is not ordered, which means we can have the right children n.right filled and n.left not.

Comment: When I run it I get 3 too. I agree that 4 is correct.

Comment: @OleV.V. That's it, and if you add another node somewhere else, you will get 1 lol. I also want to know how to assign the values to each leaf in the tree, forget about the number of children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out what was wrong in my assigning indexes code

```
    public void num(Node n) {


        if(n.getleft()!=null)num(n.getleft());
        if(n.getRight()!=null)num(n.getRight());
        if(n.isLeaf())
        {
            n.assignIndex(ini);
            ini++;
        }

}
```

Now it works well :). Thank you

Comment: Thanks for sharing. So you have `ini` declared as a field rather than a local variable now?

Comment: Yeah, cause I think when I had it as a local variable in the function, everytime I call recursion, it reinitialized to 0 ..

Answer (score 1):

If `n == null` you return 0. You should return `count` or your previous count gets lost. In your example when counting leaves for the 6 node, you correctly get 1 from the 4 node below it. Then you call `numberChild()` for the non-existing right child, it returns 0, so the count you return for the 6 node is 0, not 1.

Edit: To assign values to the leaves I believe you should use the same idea that you use for counting the nodes, pass a count to the recursive method so it knows how many leaves have already been numbered to the left of the current node, and return an updated count. You `num` method will be like another version of your `numberChild` method, extended with the assignment of new indices to the leaf nodes.

Comment: Yeah I just figuered that out and modified my code. 

Now I am trying too hard to assign values to each leaf from left to right.

For the tree above, I want that node4.index=0
node9.index=1
node8.index=2
node9.index=3